# Using multiple h1's on a page

Tags: css, html

Here I am again, asking the same question I asked a few months ago. But no, I don't believe this is a duplicate, because there are so many contradicting answers on this that I find it difficult to determine the correct one.

seroundtable.com says,

> H1 tags should be used for what they were originally created for: organizing your documents to stress the key points.

That being said, it would be illogical for search engines to *not* think that a `h2` is of lesser importance than a `h1`.

ehow.com says this,

> it is recommended that a page should always have an H1 element, but only one. The H1 tag should include the main keywords targeted within the page.

So that right there contradicts an answer provided to me on S/O a few months ago. The answer that was provided went along the lines of, 'You can have as many `h1` tags as you like' (I was asking a question about how to use them when I need more than 6).

So now I am confused.

I believe that by using many `h1`'s sends a less-than-clear message to the viewer and search engines. But I also feel dirty making a `p` tag 28px;

What should I do? The issue here is, this is a unique design, and all 5 main navigation links are spread horizontally and are all the same size. I want to use a `h1` for them all, I do not want to use `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, because all links - in this case - are of equal value. What I mean is, you wouldn't dare try to pass one page off as less important than the other.

Comment: Why not just use `h2` for all of your headers?  I tend to think of the `h1` as the page title, of which there can logically only be one.

Comment: "ehow.com says this"   You should ignore everything on that ultra low quality site.

Answer (score 2):

you can have as many h1 tags as you want in a page ([w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html)).

in your case however i would recommend using a list or for the navigation menu (wrapped in a nav element if you're using html5). The links to other pages aren't headings or the most important elements on your page.

you should reserve using h1-6 for actual headings.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using an HTML list. It seems like you are questioning what HTML element is most semantically correct, and from my experience the most semantically correct way to do navigation is using a list.

But other popular developers like Chris Coyer the author of CSS-TRICKs says he uses listless navigation. [Navigation in lists to be or not to be](http://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/).

If your site is going to used by lots of people, using a list will help those with disabilities and use screen readers to consume your website.